# Use of Pseudo-Elements in Polymer.js

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I'm taking my first steps with Polymer.js, and I'm struggling with creating a pseudo-element.

This is what I tried:

**In my host document:**

```
<style type="text/css">
  #host::x-a-cool-test {
    color: green;
  }
</style>

<div id="host">
  <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
</div>
```

**In my custom element:**

```
<element name="my-custom-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      @host {
        * { display: block; color: blue; }
      }          
     </style>
     <div id="group" pseudo="x-a-cool-test">
        just some text
     </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer.register(this);
  </script>
</element>
```

That will show `just my text` in blue. That is correct, because according to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/), *rules wrapped in a `@host` have higher specificity than any selector in the parent page*.

**My question**:

If I delete `color: blue` from inside the `@host` block in my template, the text is shown in black and NOT green as I would expect. Why is that???

Comment: There's not such thing as "@host". There's only ":host" - you need to prefix each selector with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X1gUJO1dhr5JsqQwi4uv?p=preview) works how you want it to. Basically, the CSS pseudo-element has to be applied directly to the custom element (in this case the `my-custom-element`). I switched `id="host"` to it (instead of its parent `div`) and the code worked.

```
<div>
  <my-custom-element id="host"></my-custom-element>
</div>
```

**Note:** The overriding nature of @host [may change](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=21959). Some (myself included) think it should be more for providing default, fallback styles. In this case rules in the host document will override @host rules instead of the other way around.