# Can I add pseudo-element for the paper-input's label in Polymer?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom, paper-elements

What I'm trying to do is add an asterisk (*) at the end of a paper-input's label if it has `required` class. In normal CSS, I can use `.required label::after {}`, but how do I do this in Polymer?

I'm aware of using the `--paper-input-container-label` mix-in, but that applies directly to the `<label>`, not adding pseudo-element.

Is this even possible in Polymer?

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274179/use-of-pseudo-elements-in-polymer-js